# Prob. 8, Sec. 4.2 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: Nonnegativity of a subadditive functional outside a sphere implies nonnegativity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If a subadditive functional $p$ defined on a normed space $X$ is non-negative outside a sphere $\{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ \Vert x \Vert = r \ \}$, then how to show that $p$ is non-negative for all $x \in X$?

For all $x, y \in X$, we have $p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y)$.

And, $p(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$ such that $\Vert x \Vert > r$, where $r$ is a given positive real number.

Let $v \in X$ be arbitrary. Let $v$ be non-zero.

Let 
$$x \colon =  \frac{r+1}{\Vert v \Vert  }  v.$$ 
Then  $\Vert x \Vert = r+1$. So we must have $p(x) \geq 0$.

What next?

PS:

Here is a solution:

> First, we show that 
>   $$ n p(x) \geq p(nx) \ \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}. \tag{0} $$
>   For $n = 1$, this holds trivially. So if this holds for any given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we find that
>   $$ (n+1)p(x) = np(x) + p(x) \geq p(nx) + p(x) \geq p(nx+x) = p\big( (n+1) x \big). $$
>   Hence (0) holds for all natural numbers $n$.
>
> We are given that, there is a (non-negative) real number $r$ such that
>   $$ p(x) \geq 0 \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X \mbox{ such that } \lVert x \rVert > r. \tag{1} $$
>
> Let $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x \rVert \leq r$. There are two cases according as $\lVert x \rVert > 0$ or $\lVert x \rVert = 0$.
>
> Case 1: If $\lVert x \rVert > 0$, then let us choose a natural number $n$ such that 
>   $$ \lVert nx \rVert = n \lVert x \rVert > r. $$
>   This along with (0) amd (1) above yields
>   $$ n p(x) \geq p(nx) \geq 0, $$
>   and as $n > 0$, so we obtain
>   $$ p(x) \geq 0. $$
>
> Before considering the case $\lVert x \rVert = 0$, we note that, for any $x, y \in X$, we have
>   $$ p(x) = p(x - y + y) \leq p(x-y) + p(y), $$
>   and so
>   $$ p(x) - p(y) \leq p(x-y),   $$
>   which is the same as 
>   $$ p(x-y) \geq p(x) - p(y). \tag{2} $$
>
> Case 2: If $\lVert x \rVert = 0$, then $x = \mathbf{0}_X$, the zero vector in $X$. In this case we use (2) above and find that, for any $x \in X$, 
>   $$ p\left( \mathbf{0}_X \right) = p\big(x - x \big) \geq p(x) - p(x) = 0, $$
>   and so
>   $$  p\left( \mathbf{0}_X \right) \geq 0, $$
>   as required.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it clear enough?

Comment: $x$ nonnegative outside of the sphere. Try to write $p(x)<\sum p(1/a x)$ to see that everything in the sphere is nonnegative as well.

Comment: @Eoin, can you please read my question carefully once again? Your comment is not clear to me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there...you might have just missed a simple trick. Note that in your solution you have not yet used the fact that $p$ is a subadditive functional. Here is how you can use it. For any $v\in X$ let $n$ be an integer such that $n\geq \frac{r+1}{\|v\|}$. Then it follows that $p(nv)\geq 0$. In particular, 
\begin{equation}
0\leq p(nv) = p(v+\ldots+v)\leq np(v).
\end{equation}
Therefore, $p(v)\geq 0$.

Comment: and how to tackle the case when $v = \theta$, the zero vector in $X$? Did they make any vidoes of your B. Maths (Hons.) courses?

Comment: $v=\theta$ is not a problem because by taking $x=y=\theta$ you can easily see that $p(\theta)\geq0$....and there were no videos made of the class lectures....